# Google apps script UrlFetchApp.fetch request domain (com.au) oddity

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I've been trying to use an external API to populate a Google Sheet with shipping prices from an Australian API.

When posting the request, Appscript seems to be changing the `.com.au` part of the domain to `<?>`.

I'm getting a 401 error like so (you can see the `.<?>` ):

> `Request failed for https://www.transdirect.<?>/api/quotes returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"message":"You are not permitted to access this area.","code":401,"success":false} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 36, file "TransDirect API Handler")`

Anyone know how I can stop this from happening in my request?
Here is the code (I've removed the API key.) :

```
function Quote() {


var url= "https://www.transdirect.com.au/api/quotes";
var payload = {'declared_value': '100.00',
  'items': [
    {
      'weight': '38.63',
      'height': '0.25',
      'width': '1.65',
      'length': '3.32',
      'quantity': 1,
      'description': 'carton'
    },
    {
      'weight': '39.63',
      'height': '1.25',
      'width': '2.65',
      'length': '4.32',
      'quantity': 2,
      'description': 'carton'
    }
  ],
  'sender': {
    'postcode': '3',
    'suburb': 'SYDNEY',
    'type': 'business',
    'country': 'AU'
  },
  'receiver': {
    'postcode': '3000',
    'suburb': 'MELBOURNE',
    'type': 'business',
    'country': 'AU'
  }};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
            url,
            {
              'method' : 'post',
              'contentType': 'application/json',
              'Api-Key': '<API KEY HERE>',
              'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload),
            }
);
var responseCode = response.getResponseCode()
var responseBody = response.getContentText()

if (responseCode === 200) {
  var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody)
} else {
  Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s", responseCode, responseBody)
            );

}
};
```

Would you say this is a bug in UrlFetchApp or am I doing something wrong?

Just to clarify, I've tested the API-Key on apiary.io with no dramas (it works).

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UrlFetch` is performing the request. You are getting an error from the REST interface because probably your payload is missing the api key in `headers`.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, 
  {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'headers': {                    // you need this header field
      'Api-key': '<API KEY HERE>',  // Api-key with lowcase k
    },
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload),
  });
```

I've not tested it, but I'm quite confident it works.

Comment: You are a Legend. I've got it working a treat! Next step is to map the output to the correct cells in my g sheet.

Comment: Good luck with the next step :) Glad that it helped.

Comment: One more thing @Matteo, do you have an opinion on how the interface is converting the `.com.au` to `<?>` ?
It is still doing this despite the fix.

Comment: I really don't know :/